# my function to sort a shared pointer list in c++ is not completing the sort

Tags: c++, list, sorting, pointers, shared

I have an STL `std::list` of 5 shared pointers that point to node objects needing to be sorted by their respective `id` numbers.

```
do
{
    check = 0, i = 0;
    auto it = newList.begin();

    while (i < newList.size() - 1)
    {
        first = *it;
        second = *++it;

        if (comp_id(first, second))
        {
            temp = second;
            second = first;
            first = temp;
            check = 1;
        }

        i++;
    }
} while (check == 1);
```

In this code, the `comp_id()` returns true, and runs through the organization, but nothing is changing in the `list` while it happens. I was hoping to get some perspective as to why this is happening, and how to fix it.

P.S. I am not allowed to use the `list_name.sort()` method :(

Comment: `second = *++it;` Here you probably need: `second = *(it+1);`

Comment: Confirm that your teacher has a sense of humour and then use `std::sort`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau (nice name BTW) my professor has limited me to not use the sort function in order for us to have a more complete grasp on what shared pointers and lists are specifically. With that said I understand now that I am not actually editing the list, my question now is how can I go about doing exactly that.

Comment: @NicholasProvencal simply change your `first` and `second` variables into iterators, and then dereference them when passing their values to `comp_id()`, or swapping their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are making modifications only to local variables (`first` and `second`) which are *copies* of values from the list.  You are not modifying the actual content of the list at all.

To make the code work, simply change your `first` and `second` variables into list iterators, and then dereference them whenever you want to access their values, eg:

```
auto size = newList.size();
if (size > 1)
{
    --size;
    do
    {
        check = 0, i = 0;
        auto it = newList.begin();

        while (i < size)
        {
            auto first = it;
            auto second = ++it;

            if (comp_id(*first, *second))
            {
                auto temp = *second;
                *second = *first;
                *first = temp;
                check = 1;
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }
    while (check == 1);
}
```

For that matter, `i` can be replaced with an iterator, as well:

```
if (newList.size() > 1)
{
    auto begin = newList.begin();
    auto end = newList.end()-1;
    do
    {
        check = 0;
        auto it = begin;

        while (it != end)
        {
            auto first = it;
            auto second = ++it;

            if (comp_id(*first, *second))
            {
                auto temp = *second;
                *second = *first;
                *first = temp;
                check = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (check == 1);
}
```

Comment: Ah, so I needed to dereference each of the pointers in order to have the method actually edit the list. what I was doing was just swapping the around pointers to pointers, correct?

Comment: @NicholasProvencal Something like that. In your original code, `first` and `second` are local `shared_ptr<node>` objects since you are dereferencing `it`, so `first = *it` and `second = *++it` are making *copies* of the objects from the list, and then you are comparing/swapping the *copies*, not the *originals*. By changing the `first` and `second` variables into iterators, you are avoiding the *copies* and comparing/swapping the *originals* directly.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much this helped me solve most of the problems for the rest of my code as well.

Comment: I have added another issue to the original question hoping you could shed some light

Comment: @NicholasProvencal it is not the same issue, you should have posted it as a new question with a [mcve]. In any case, the only thing I see is `bikelist` is passed in by value instead of by reference, so a *copy* of the list is made, but that doesn't affect the outcome as the code is not modifying `bikelist` itself, so passing by value is just a missed optimization. The code is accessing the original `Bike` objects that the original list is pointing at. There are no `Bike` copies being made. So what is the actual problem you are having? What does "global scope" have to do with anything?

Comment: i posted it as a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053869/using-incorrect-syntax-to-change-global-scope