# Need help figuriing out correct syntax to update objects in global scope

Tags: pointers, scope, iterator, global, local

I have this code:

```
int do_transact(ifstream & inFile, list<shared_ptr<Bike>> bikelist, status s)
{
    int id, i = 0, size = bikelist.size();
    float days;
    string str, str2;
    char name[50];
    list<shared_ptr<Bike>>::iterator it = bikelist.begin();


    if (s == NO_STATUS) //performs rental
    {
        inFile >> id;
        inFile >> days;

        inFile >> str;
        inFile >> str2;
        strcpy_s(name, str.c_str());


        while (i < size)
        {
            if (id == (*it)->id_num) // rents bike
            {
                cout << "vvvvvv PERFORMING RENTAL vvvvvv" << endl << endl;
                cout << "The price of this rental will be: $" << (days)*((*it)->cost_per_day) << endl;
                strcpy_s((*it)->to_whom, name);
                (*it)->rented_code = RENTED;
                cout << "Thank you for your business!" << endl << endl;
                return 0;
            }

            i++;
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to change `to_whom` and `rented_code` in the original list, but it is not updating.

What is the syntax I need in order to change these values the way I need?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The only thing I see is `bikelist` is passed by value instead of by reference, so a *copy* of the list is made, but since the list only has pointers, that doesn't affect the outcome as the code is not modifying `bikelist` itself. Passing by value is just a missed optimization. The code is accessing the original `Bike` objects that the original list is pointing at.

Comment: Please debug your code to make sure that 1) `status` is actually `NO_STATUS`, 2) `bikelist` is not empty, and 3) `inFile` contains the input data you are expecting. I can't reproduce the issue using the code you have shown, [it works fine for me](https://ideone.com/nhUtwd). The original list objects are updated as expected, provided that all of the inputs are correct.